# .Net MAUI Behaviour vs Trigger vs VisualState

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, maui

I have no prior experience with Xamarin. Thus, since the official MAUI documentation is now very extensive, I started reading about the fundamentals. But after reading I'm not entirely sure about the differences between behaviours, triggers and visual states regarding use cases.

The documentation uses almost the same example for all three, validate an entries input and change a color accordingly. Aside from behaviours being more reusable and triggers and states being more usable for styling/theming (as far as I understand) there doesn't seem much difference in what they do. So I was wondering if someone could explain a little about when to use which approach and their limits/advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to? trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers behaviors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors visual-states: https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/user-interface/visual-states.md

Comment: Docs-Maui https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui and .net maui https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/

Comment: I'm referring to the three sections in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/  , which is identical to the github content